# Can't get PHP working with MySQL (using Linux)

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Alright, when I compile this bit of code to test:

```
<?php

   require('index.inc');
   $page = new buildpage();
   $page->buildHeader();


   $dbase = $mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');


<?php
   $page->buildFooter();
?>
```

I'm getting:

> ```
> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: mysqli_connect in
> ```
>
> /home/tim/Documents/Web/index2.php
>   on line 9 PHP Stack trace: PHP   1.
>   {main}()
>   /home/tim/Documents/Web/index2.php:0
>   PHP Fatal error:  Function name must
>   be a string in
>   /home/tim/Documents/Web/index2.php
>   on line 9 PHP Stack trace: PHP   1.
>   {main}()
>   /home/tim/Documents/Webindex2.php:0

I located my mysql.so file and set it accordingly in my php.ini, but for some reason the mysql extension doesn't seem to be working... unless there's something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `mysqli_connect` is a *function* and not a *variable*. Remove the `$` sign.

```
$dbase = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
```

Comment: stupid stupid mistake on my part! can't believe i missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, remove the $.  If you're trying to squelch potential error messages, use @.